# elisp - Get path to file relative to script

Tags: emacs, elisp, relative-path

Say I am writing an emacs lisp function that interfaces with a file located relative to the file in which the function is defined.

```
- bin/executable
- foo.el
```

`foo.el`:

```
(defun foo ()
  (shell-command-to-string
   (format "echo '%s' | ./bin/executable"
           (buffer-substring-no-properties
            (point-min)
            (point-max)))))
```

If I run this from `foo.el` then it works great. If I invoke the function while editing any other file it doesn't work because the path ain't right.

How can I reliably reference `./bin/executable` from within `foo.el` no matter where the function is invoked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `load-file-name` variable.

```el
(defconst directory-of-foo (file-name-directory load-file-name))

(defun foo ()
  (shell-command-to-string
   (format "echo '%s' | %s"
           (buffer-substring-no-properties
            (point-min)
            (point-max))
           (expand-file-name "./bin/executable" directory-of-foo))))
```

Comment: This worked. Though I opted for `(defconst path-of-foo (file-name-directory (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)))` instead.

Comment: FWIW, the convention in the GNU project is to use "path" only to mean "list of directories in which to search" (as in "$PATH") so we'd call the above variable "directory-of-foo" instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of `load-file-name` and `default-directory`. If you only check the former, the file will work if you explicitly load it, but it will not work if you eval it in a buffer.

For example:

```
(defvar my-directory (if load-file-name
                         ;; File is being loaded.
                         (file-name-directory load-file-name)
                       ;; File is being evaluated using, for example, `eval-buffer'.
                       default-directory))
```

In addition, it might be a good idea to convert the path to an absolute path using `expand-file-name`.